# google spreadsheets currency format with suffix

Tags: google-sheets, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I have cells with data in a format:

`12 345,67 EUR`

(twelve thousand three hundred forty five EUR and sixty seven cents)

I can't change this format (I need to copy&paste a lot of those into the spreadsheet from another source).

I'm trying to make some calculations with it but it shows me `#VALUE!` error saying it's a text and cannot be coerced to a number. I tried to format those cells as custom number format `##,###.00" EUR"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[ EUR]"; )*1
```

[image]

Comment: It works ! Still looks to me more like a workaround.